# Vectorised time zone conversion with lubridate

Tags: r, date, datetime, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data frame with a column of date-time strings:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

testdf = data_frame(
  mytz = c('Australia/Sydney', 'Australia/Adelaide', 'Australia/Perth'),
  mydt = c('2018-01-17T09:15:00', '2018-01-17T09:16:00', '2018-01-17T09:18:00'))

testdf

#  A tibble: 3 x 2
#   mytz               mydt
#   <chr>              <chr>
# 1 Australia/Sydney   2018-01-17T09:15:00
# 2 Australia/Adelaide 2018-01-17T09:16:00
# 3 Australia/Perth    2018-01-17T09:18:00
```

I want to convert these date-time strings to POSIX date-time objects with their respective timezones:

```
testdf %>% mutate(mydt_new = ymd_hms(mydt, tz = mytz))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
>     Evaluation error: `tz` argument must be a single character string.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (tz != "UTC") { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I get the same result if I use `ymd_hms` without a timezone and pipe it into `force_tz`. Is it fair to conclude that lubridate doesn't support any sort of vectorisation when it comes to timezone operations?

Comment: Perhaps `testdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(mydt_new = ymd_hms(mydt, tz = mytz))` ?

Comment: That works! I don't understand why `rowwise` would be required, though...

Comment: I suppose if it's operating on groups, and each group has one row, then tz is only length 1 in each call. That would work, even if I had multiple rows withthe same time zone. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to take this as an accepted answer, if you like!

Comment: OK. Let me handle that.

Comment: Interestingly, the tibble output from this prints the new column in `Australia/Perth`, even though I'm in `Australia/Sydney`. I wonder if that display is arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is `map2`.  It may be better to store different `tz` output in a `list` as this may get coerced to a single `tz`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- testdf %>%
         mutate(mydt_new = map2(mydt, mytz, ~ymd_hms(.x, tz = .y)))
```

If required, it can be `unnest`ed

```
out %>%
   unnest
```

The values in the `list` are

```
out %>%
   pull(mydt_new)
#[[1]]
#[1] "2018-01-17 09:15:00 AEDT"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2018-01-17 09:16:00 ACDT"

#[[3]]
#[1] "2018-01-17 09:18:00 AWST"
```

Comment: Ahh—so keep my datetimes as a list column instead? I hadn't thought about that!

Comment: @rensa  It is better because the column allows only a single timezone and coercing to a single one may be different.

Comment: In my particular use case right now, coercing to a single timezone isn't problematic, but I agree that this is more generally preferable :)

Comment: @rensa What is interesting is that if I use the `unnest` i get a different value compared to the jazzuro's one.  So, it would be coercing to different `tz`

Comment: Although `rowwise` and `ungroup` are a good solution, I think this is probably the preferable in order to keep the time zone info as it is.

Comment: @rensa I think jazzurro's is also correct as you don't really mind with a single timezone.  His answer coerces to ` "Australia/Perth"` which is the last entry while mine coerces to `UTC` after `unnest` i.e. `out %>% unnest %>% pull(mydt_new) %>% tz(.)`

Comment: If I were able I'd accept both your answers  But I think that, as a general case, it's a good idea to prioritise the predictability of the output.

Comment: @akrun I lately answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833660/convert-to-local-time-zone-from-latitude-and-longitude-r/59842152#59842152), which reminded me of this question. I have been wondering it is safe and/or better to keep time zones away from time. In the linked post, I created time zone as a new column and converted time to each time zone. Even after `unnest` I see correct time.  I want to know how you usually handle time. Any advice?

Comment: @jazzurro Good to hear from you.  I guess you are standardizing the time zone based on 'GMT', right?  If that is the case, I would do the same thing to get the time zone individually

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your reply. I am glad to hear that you would do the same. I'll stick to the approach. By the way, you are still rocking here. That's cool. I still have lots to learn from you.

Comment: @akrun I think you are the main contributor for my reputation. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3):

`tz argument must be a single character string.` indicates that there are more than one time zones thrown into `ymd_hms()`. In order to make sure that there is only one time zone being thrown into the function, I used `rowwise()`. Note that I am not in Australian time zone. So I am not sure if the outcome I have is identical to yours.

```
testdf <- data_frame(mytz = c('Australia/Sydney', 'Australia/Adelaide', 'Australia/Perth'),
                     mydt = c('2018-01-17 09:15:00', '2018-01-17 09:16:00', '2018-01-17 09:18:00'))

testdf %>% 
rowwise %>% 
mutate(mydt_new = ymd_hms(mydt, tz = mytz))

  mytz               mydt                mydt_new           
  <chr>              <chr>               <dttm>             
1 Australia/Sydney   2018-01-17 09:15:00 2018-01-17 06:15:00
2 Australia/Adelaide 2018-01-17 09:16:00 2018-01-17 06:46:00
3 Australia/Perth    2018-01-17 09:18:00 2018-01-17 09:18:00
```

Comment: Yep, I get the same output. It also appears that the tibble printing method chooses a timezone from those in the column, rather than the user's local time zone.

Comment: @rensa I see. That is something good to know.  Thanks for the information. :)

Comment: @jazzurro I posted as a solution as it was interesting comparison about how the timezones are coerced.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @akrun I realized you were askign to check the code you have in the deleted comment. I just could not reply to you at that moment. Sorry.  I think you investigated an interesting case. I have something to ask more in this point, but I cannot commit myself here right now. Could I contact you here later?

Comment: @jazzurro  sure, I thought it would give the correct answer, but the timezone change happens earlier.  So, wrapping with `list` didn't help and so i deleted that code

Comment: @akrun Finally, I am settled. Seeing the difference, I first wondered how my code  worked. I thought I was creating a date object with a time zone (e.g., the 1st row with Sydney). Then I realized that the results were displayed with the time zone for Perth. Did the code initially produce date objects in accordance with the time zones? I also had another question, but this requires more typing. Whenever you have time, would you be able to chat?

Comment: @jazzurro  Sure, right now I have a call within 10 minutes.  Talk to you later  I think the rowwise is somehow coercing it to a single timezone otherwise, wrapping with `list` would have saved it

Comment: @akrun Got it. Let me know when you find a bit of spare time.

Comment: @jazzurro  If you do the `as.character` the type will be different, but it should get the similar values `testdf %>% rowwise %>%  mutate(mydt_new = as.character(ymd_hms(mydt, tz = mytz)))`

Comment: @akrun If I followed your idea and did the following. `testdf %>% 
rowwise %>% mutate(mydt_new = format(ymd_hms(mydt, tz = mytz), usetz = TRUE))`.

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I think so too. As long as the result stay in list, we cannot see what is there. So having this type of information is a good thing. By the way, given some time difference, it may be hard to have a chat. Let me briefly explain the question I have. Just like the OP here, I had some moments that I received error message in mutate(). I cannot come up with any specific case since I do not remember any now. In these cases rowwise was the solution. Have you come across this kind of moment? I think the key thing that I am missing is when rowwise is required.

Comment: @akrun I am not particularly surprised to see why the OP got confused since he was expecting two elements in each row to be passed to ymd_hms(). But that was not the case. I wish I can come up with an example, but this is all I can tell right now.

Comment: @jazzurro I think the `map` functions could be faster compared to `rowwise`  (if I am not mistaken).  In this specific case, if it is not kept in a list, the timezone would collapse.  But, let's say if we have a rowwise operation and the return values have the same type etc.  then one of the map extensions like `map_lgl`, map_dbl etc could be useful.

Comment: @akrun Yeah I think rowwise is slow (or slower).  Can we use `Map()` as well?  Yesterday, I had no issue with `testdf %>% mutate(new.time = Map(function(x, y) ymd_hms(x, tz = y), mytz, mydt)`. But today I get warning messages.

Comment: @akrun My bad. the order of x and y argument was the other way around. Now what is the advantage of using map2 here compared to the classic Map?

Comment: @jazzurro  I guess the purrr functions are consistent in the order of function arguments.  I haven't checked whether there is any speed advantage or not.  But I am assuming that these functions are optimized

Comment: @akrun I see. Thank you for that info. Going back to what I mentioned ealier, what did the OP's code did not work? Obviously, there was more than one time zones getting in to the tz argument, but why was that the case?

Comment: @jazzurro  The reason would be `ymd_hms` takes a single `tz` and is not vectorized for tz.  As there are multiple `tz` it breaks up.  If you do `testdf %>% mutate(mydt_new = ymd_hms(mydt, tz = mytz[1]))` it works.  The error is not related to `mutate` i.e. if you do it outside the chain `ymd_hms(testdf$mydt, tz = testdf$mytz)#
Error in C_force_tz(time, tz = tzone, roll) : 
  `tz` argument must be a single character string

Comment: @akrun Got it. So if you see similar behavior in mutate, you would want to suspect a similar reason staying behind error message?

Comment: @jazzurro There are certain class types the `mutate` would give error.  For e.g. `POSIXlt` class