# Convert to local time zone from latitude and longitude R

Tags: r, timezone, latitude-longitude, lubridate, localtime

I have one data frame with a lot of locations (around 30.000), and I need to convert the time of each location for the local time.
I tried some ideas like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414340/convert-to-local-time-zone-using-latitude-and-longitude), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408507/get-the-local-time-from-a-utc-time?noredirect=1&lq=1). But they did not work for me.

I have data like this:

```
dt = data.table(date = c("2018-01-16 22:02:37",
                         "2018-01-16 22:54:00", 
                         "2018-01-16 23:08:38"),
                lat = c(-54.5010,
                        -54.5246,
                        -54.5285),
                long = c(-25.0433, 
                         -25.0929,
                         -25.0832))
```

And I expected this output:

```
date                      lat           long
2018-01-16 20:02:37       -54.5010      -25.0433
2018-01-16 20:54:00       -54.5246      -25.0929
2018-01-16 21:08:38       -54.5285      -25.0832
```

One try:

```
library(sf)
dt = data.table(date = c("2018-01-16 22:02:37",
                         "2018-01-16 22:54:00", 
                         "2018-01-16 23:08:38"),
                lat = c(-54.5010,
                        -54.5246,
                        -54.5285),
                long = c(-25.0433, 
                         -25.0929,
                         -25.0832))

sdf = st_as_sf(dt, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

## import timezones (after extraction) and intersect with spatial points
tzs = st_read("timezones.geojson/combined.json", quiet = TRUE) #HERE DONT WORK
sdf = st_join(sdf, tzs)

## convert timestamps to local time
sdf$timeL = as.POSIXlt(sdf$time1, tz = as.character(sdf$tzid))
sdf$timeL
```

```
Cannot open data source timezones.geojson/combined.json

Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  Open failed.
```

Then I tried:

```
library(lutz)
library(sf)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

download.file("https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder/releases/download/2019a/timezones-with-oceans.geojson.zip",
              destfile = "tz.zip")
unzip("tz.zip", exdir = "data-raw/dist/")
tz_full <- read_sf("data-raw/dist/combined-with-oceans.json")
```

But this didn't work either.

```
Cannot open data source ~/Dropbox/Érika Project/mestrado_R/bhv_loc_R/tables/data-raw/dist/combined-with-oceans.json
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
  Open failed.
```

I got it just like this:

```
library(lutz)

v <- tz_lookup_coords(lat = dt$lat, lon = dt$lon, method = "accurate")
v1<-as.data.frame(v)
```

The output:

```
[1] "America/Bahia" "Etc/GMT+3"     "Etc/GMT+3"     "Etc/GMT+3"     "Etc/GMT+3"     "Etc/GMT+3"
```

But with this output I dont know how can I convert the timezones.

I thought in do something like this:

```
v1$tzone <- NA
v1[v1$v == "America/Bahia", "tzone"] <- "+3" 
v1[v1$v == "America/Sao_Paulo", "tzone"] <- "+3" 
v1[v1$v == "Etc/GMT+2", "tzone"] <- "+2" 
v1[v1$v == "Etc/GMT+3", "tzone"] <- "+3" 

  if (v1$tzone == "+3" ) {
  v1$timeBR <- NA
  v1$timeBR <- strptime(v1$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  v1$timeBR <- v1$timeBR -3*3600 #creating a column corresponding to local Brazilian time (UTC -3)
  v1$hourBR <- as.POSIXlt(v1$timeBR)$hour
  v1 <- v1[!is.na(v1$timeBR),]
  }

#But the function not works (I dont know do functions), would gonna be better one function with the two condition +3 and +2
```

**EDIT**

With the suggestion:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 2 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.5.2 
> library(lutz)
Warning message:
package ‘lutz’ was built under R version 3.5.2 
> library(purrr)

Attaching package: ‘purrr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    transpose

> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    hour, isoweek, mday, minute, month, quarter, second, wday, week, yday, year

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

#t it is the original data
> head(t$time)
[1] 2017-10-16 17:01:00 2017-10-16 18:35:22 2017-10-16 20:38:54 2017-10-16 21:27:27 2017-10-16 21:43:20
[6] 2017-10-16 23:24:46
27092 Levels: 2016-10-24 15:42:00 2016-10-24 21:03:28 2016-10-24 22:04:35 2016-10-24 23:13:40 ... 2020-01-10 11:34:21
> class(t$time)
[1] "factor"
> date2<-t$time
> class(date2)
[1] "factor"
> date2<- as.character(t$time)
> class(date2)
[1] "character"
> head(date2)
[1] "2017-10-16 17:01:00" "2017-10-16 18:35:22" "2017-10-16 20:38:54" "2017-10-16 21:27:27" "2017-10-16 21:43:20"
[6] "2017-10-16 23:24:46"
> t[, date2 := as.POSIXct(date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")][,
+                                                                          timezone := tz_lookup_coords(lat = lat, lon = long, method = "accurate")][,
+                                                                                                                                                    new_time := map2(.x = date2, .y = timezone, 
+                                                                                                                                                                     .f = function(x, y) {with_tz(time = x, tzone = y)})][]
Error in `:=`(date2, as.POSIXct(date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

**EDIT2**

**I found what was going wrong, my original data wasn't in data.table and data.frame format!
Then, now I have this list inside the data. Im trying to convert in one new column**

**EDIT 3**

**NOW WORKED! THANKS TO ALL FOR COMMENTS AND HELP**

```
t[, date2 := as.POSIXct(date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")]
[,timezone := tz_lookup_coords(lat = lat, lon = lon, method = "accurate")]
[,new_time := map2(.x = date2, .y = timezone,
.f = function(x, y) {with_tz(time = x, tzone = y)})][]

newtime<-do.call(rbind, lapply(t$new_time, as.data.frame))
t$newtime<-paste(newtime$`X[[i]]`)

head(t$newtime)
[1] "2016-10-24 12:42:00" "2016-10-24 18:03:28" "2016-10-24 19:04:35" "2016-10-24 20:13:40" "2016-10-24 21:13:00"
[6] "2016-10-25 02:17:05"
```

Someone know how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how this is any different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414340/convert-to-local-time-zone-using-latitude-and-longitude which you linked? Can you give any detail about what part went wrong?

Comment: both functions allow only few locations, or just one..

Comment: The second answer to the linked question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49996425/496803 looks to only use local data and should support many points.

Comment: I actualized the code above

Comment: You need to download the file with the timezone boundaries from the linked site over there ( https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder ), extract it to your working directory and then try the code again.

Comment: i dont know what's going wrong, didnt works

Comment: I don't know much about sf, but you are using `read_sf` and not `st_read` as per the previous answer. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I tried here now with `st_read`, dint work too..

Comment: I managed it in a way, but I don't know how to convert the timezone with this output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I first created a date object. Then, I searched time zones with `tz_lookup_coords()` as you were trying. Then, I used `with_tz()`, which gets date-time in a different time zone. Note that `new_time` is a list as `str(dt)` indicates.

```
library(data.table)
library(lutz)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

dt[, date := as.POSIXct(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")][,
    timezone := tz_lookup_coords(lat = lat, lon = long, method = "accurate")][,
      new_time := map2(.x = date, .y = timezone, 
                       .f = function(x, y) {with_tz(time = x, tzone = y)})][]

#                  date      lat     long  timezone            new_time
#1: 2018-01-16 22:02:37 -54.5010 -25.0433 Etc/GMT+2 2018-01-16 20:02:37
#2: 2018-01-16 22:54:00 -54.5246 -25.0929 Etc/GMT+2 2018-01-16 20:54:00
#3: 2018-01-16 23:08:38 -54.5285 -25.0832 Etc/GMT+2 2018-01-16 21:08:38

#str(dt)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ date    : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-16 22:02:37" "2018-01-16 22:54:00" "2018-01-16 23:08:38"
# $ lat     : num  -54.5 -54.5 -54.5
# $ long    : num  -25 -25.1 -25.1
# $ timezone: chr  "Etc/GMT+2" "Etc/GMT+2" "Etc/GMT+2"
# $ new_time:List of 3
#  ..$ : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-16 20:02:37"
#  ..$ : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-16 20:54:00"
#  ..$ : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-16 21:08:38"
```

**A bit more help**

If you have a data frame, you can use tidyverse approaches too. I used your `dt` here. I converted it to a data.frame object. The last thin you need is `unnest()`. Then, you will have time in a column.

```
setDF(dt) %>% 
mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT"),
       timezone = tz_lookup_coords(lat = lat, lon = long, method = "accurate"),
       new_time = map2(.x = date, .y = timezone, 
                       .f = function(x, y) {with_tz(time = x, tzone = y)})) %>% 
unnest(new_time) 

   date                  lat  long timezone  new_time           
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dttm>             
1 2018-01-16 22:02:37 -54.5 -25.0 Etc/GMT+2 2018-01-16 20:02:37
2 2018-01-16 22:54:00 -54.5 -25.1 Etc/GMT+2 2018-01-16 20:54:00
3 2018-01-16 23:08:38 -54.5 -25.1 Etc/GMT+2 2018-01-16 21:08:38

> str(foo)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date    : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-16 22:02:37" "2018-01-16 22:54:00" "2018-01-16 23:08:38"
 $ lat     : num  -54.5 -54.5 -54.5
 $ long    : num  -25 -25.1 -25.1
 $ timezone: chr  "Etc/GMT+2" "Etc/GMT+2" "Etc/GMT+2"
 $ new_time: POSIXct, format: "2018-01-16 20:02:37" "2018-01-16 20:54:00" "2018-01-16 21:08:38"
```

Comment: Thank you! When I run with the example its ok! but when I tried with my data, didn't work.. `Error in `:=`(date2, as.POSIXct(date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").` I notice that in example the date was in character, then I convert my original data to character too, but didnt work

Comment: @ÉrikaSoaresCoelho I added a tydyverse approach for you. The key is to use `unnest()`. I hope this is enough for you.